# Fastest way to get git status in bash

Tags: git, bash

For a while now I've been using the `__git_ps1` function in my bash's PS1 prompt
(with `PS1='\w$(__git_ps1)'`). Now I want to color it depending on branch
status.

I wrote a bash function that checks if the current branch is modified, and
colors red or white depending on the status. The problem is that it uses `git
status` to check the status (it's the only way I know off), and that's several
times slower than `__git_ps1`, which is enough to cause an annoying delay when
I'm using the prompt (I'm on a very weak netbook).

So I ask: is there a faster way to check status of the current git folder?
`__git_ps1` is a lot faster than manually parsing `git branch`, so I'm thinking
there might be some other hidden git function.

Comment: To clarify for myself: Do you want to know if the branch has untracked files?

Comment: @PetervanderDoes yes. Anything that would be reported by `git status`.

Comment: Note: Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015) should improve this. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32039972/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not entirely your answer, but bash-completion has this built-in.

If you set the bash ENV GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE to a nonempty value, unstaged (*) and staged (+) changes will be shown next to the branch name.  You can configure this per-repository ith the bash.showDirtyState variable, which defaults to true once GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE is enabled.

You can also see if currently something is stashed, by setting GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE to a nonempty value. If something is stashed, then a '$' will be shown next to the branch name.

If you would like to see if there are untracked files, then you can set GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES to a nonempty value. If there are untracked files, then a '%' will be shown next to the branch name.

Not sure about the speed degrade when you enable this though.
If you want to do the coloring:

Staged files:

```
if git rev-parse --quiet --verify HEAD >/dev/null; then
 git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD -- || color for staged changes
else
  color unstaged changes
fi
```

Stashed files

```
git rev-parse --verify refs/stash >/dev/null 2>&1 && color for stashed files
```

Untracked files

```
if [ -n "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard)" ]; then
  Color untrack files
fi
```

The above snippets come from the bash-completion script.

Comment: Nice answer, but the first script isn't working for me. It seems `git rev-parse
--quiet --verify HEAD >/dev/null` is always returning `0` no matter the
staged/unstaged state.

Comment: The only way it won't work for me is when I don't have a branch yet. What's the output of `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`

Comment: A large hexadecimal number. I tried playing around with branches a bit, but it just always returns 0. That's not much of a problem though, it's the other stuff that I decided to go with the GIT_PS1 variables. Where did you find out about them?

Comment: The number is a good thing, the command itself works. Not sure why it returns 0 in your case.

The snippets are from the bash completion script. It's installed when you install git. The __git_ps1 is a command in that script. You can find it in the source of git in the directory contrib/completion

Answer (score 6):

Note: Git 2.6+ (Q3 2015) should accelerate that `__git_ps1` status:

See [commit dd160d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd160d794f0bf02c30d2e5032e216b1e8ac14222), [commit 6bfab99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bfab998b5046e8f4f7b0ae4833ba4babf92de83) (19 Jul 2015) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 461c119](https://github.com/git/git/commit/461c119739389430e9f978426f25a12690a1831c), 03 Aug 2015)</sup>

> ## bash prompt: faster untracked status indicator with untracked directories
>
> If the untracked status indicator is enabled, `__git_ps1()` looks for untracked files by running '`git ls-files`'.
> This can be perceptibly slow in case of an untracked directory containing lot of files, because it lists all files found in the untracked directory only to be redirected into `/dev/null` right away.
> This is the actual command run by `__git_ps1()`:

```
$ ls untracked-dir/ |wc -l
100000
$ time git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --error-unmatch \
  -- ':/*' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

real    0m0.955s
user    0m0.936s
sys 0m0.016s
```

> **Eliminate this delay by additionally passing the '`--directory --no-empty-directory`' options to '`git ls-files`' to show only the name of non-empty untracked directories instead of all their content**:

```
$ time git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory \
  --no-empty-directory --error-unmatch -- ':/*' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.000s
```

> This follows suit of [ea95c7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea95c7b8f52471f7ce30379c2b2d7032f2b8c2c9) (completion: improve untracked directory
> filtering for filename completion, 2013-09-18, git 1.8.5).

---

Make sure to tuse Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), as a leakfix is available in a part of the code which influences `git ls-files`.

See [commit eceba53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eceba5321410bbcc9e0b11e6aa479832f574eca8), [commit dad4f23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dad4f23ce59339bb32ad9e1cc1682c696f7a724f) (18 Aug 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ad00f44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad00f44f5479441da59bd55261ae717fcb357938), 24 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eceba5321410bbcc9e0b11e6aa479832f574eca8): fix problematic API to avoid memory leaks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> The `dir` structure seemed to have a number of leaks and problems around it.
>
> First I noticed that `parent_hashmap` and `recursive_hashmap` were being leaked (though Peff noticed and submitted fixes before me).
>
> Then I noticed in the previous commit that `clear_directory()` was only taking responsibility for a subset of fields within `dir_struct,` despite the fact that entries[] and ignored[] we allocated internally to [`dir.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eceba5321410bbcc9e0b11e6aa479832f574eca8/dir.c).
> That, of course, resulted in many callers either leaking or haphazardly trying to free these arrays and their contents.
>
> Digging further, I found that despite the pretty clear documentation near the top of [`dir.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eceba5321410bbcc9e0b11e6aa479832f574eca8/dir.h) that folks were supposed to call `clear_directory()` when the user no longer needed the `dir_struct,` there were four callers that didn't bother doing that at all.
> However, two of them clearly thought about leaks since they had an `UNLEAK(dir)` directive, which to me suggests that the method to free the data was too unclear.
> I suspect the non-obviousness of the API and its holes led folks to avoid it, which then snowballed into further problems with the `entries[]`, `ignored[]`, `parent_hashmap,` and `recursive_hashmap` problems.
>
> Rename `clear_directory()` to `dir_clear()` to be more in line with other data structures in git, and introduce a `dir_init()` to handle the suggested memsetting of `dir_struct` to all zeroes.
> I hope that a name like `"dir_clear()`" is more clear, and that the presence of `dir_init()` will provide a hint to those looking at the code that they need to look for either a `dir_clear()` or a `dir_free()` and lead them to find `dir_clear()`.

That influences:

- `git add`
- `git check-ignore`
- `git clean`
- `git grep`
- `git ls-files`
- `git stash`
- `git merge`

Answer (score 4):

`git diff --quiet` returns 1 if there are changes to the working directory, and `git diff --quiet --cached` does the same for the index.

You can use it to do:

```
git diff --quiet
    || echo "There be changes!"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
! git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD      # fastest staged-changes test
! git diff-files --quiet                    # fastest unstaged-changes test
! git diff-index --quiet          HEAD      # fastest any-changes test
stdbuf -oL git ls-files -o | grep -qs .     # fastest untracked-files test
git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash >&-    # fastest any-stash test
```

If ignored status matters for untracked files use `--exclude-standard -oi` for untracked-ignored and `--exclude-standard -o` for untracked and unignored.

The fastest way I know to get a HEAD moniker (branch name or sha) is

```
{ git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git rev-parse -q --short --verify HEAD; } 2>&-
```

which leaves a return code if you're not in a repo, so you can e.g.

```
if HEAD=`{ git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD;  } 2>&-`
then
        : in a git repo, $HEAD is the branch name or sha
fi
```

NOTE that the untracked-files test depends on running with `shopt -s lastpipe` for `bash`.  `zsh` and `ksh` operate that way by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ksh and am having the same problem.  To top it off, my Git repos are on NFS mounts making the response time even slower.

To directly answer the question about speed, try using:

```
git ls-files -m
```

appears to be significantly faster than 'git status -s', after first entering a different repository.  Once within a repository, the OS and NFS caching appear to drastically speed this command up.  This command also appears to be very speedy when deep inside the bottom leafs of the git working directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions with `git` eventually get capped at how fast `git` runs. You can get `git` itself to run faster than that by using feeding some fs-monitoring hooks into git:

- https://github.com/jgavris/rs-git-fsmonitor uses Facebook's Watchman to look for file changes.

Or you can do less work, like `--directory --no-empty-directory` but going further:

- https://github.com/romkatv/gitstatus additionally uses less syscalls and terminates scans early